# Failed to manipulate the list SQL-Query in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have a query bring the SQL-Query list of Hibernate XML
Ask a question about if I want to capture the values ​​of a query column in a variable I get failed:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.openSession().getNamedQuery("getListCustomers");

List<Customer> listaResultados = query.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < listaResultados.size(); i++)        {
            System.out.println("Nombre " + i + ": " + listaResultados.get(i));

            Map values = (Map) listaResultados.get(i);
            Integer code = Integer.parseInt(values.get("code").toString());
            System.out.println("===> code: "+code);

        }
```

This leaves me in console, in failed in Map:

```
Hibernate: SELECT  ba_customer_id, 
                ba_company_id, 
                code, 
                name, 
                comercial_name, 
                discount, 
                is_active, 
                created, 
                observation
        FROM ba_customer

exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Map] con causa raíz
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

Comment: It would help if you post the actual query, which probably returns a Customer object instead of a String.

Answer (score 1):

Your list should not be a `List<String>`, it should be of the type returned by Hibernate, your entity. Assuming that's customer

```
List<Customer> listaResultados = query.list();
```

What you have

```
List<String> listaResultados = query.list();
```

doesn't make sense unless your named query returns a List of String names or something of the sort, which apparently it doesn't since you're getting the exception.